# Read matrix of string

Tags: string, matlab, file-read

I need to read a text file like this (columns can be 6,9,12, etc..):

```
R,R,S,S,T,T
R,R,S,T,S,T
R,R,S,T,T,S
R,R,T,S,S,T
R,R,T,S,T,S
R,R,T,T,S,S
R,S,R,S,T,T
R,S,R,T,S,T
R,S,R,T,T,S
R,S,S,R,T,T
R,S,S,T,R,T
```

and put data in a matrix of string (without commas).

I've tried with `mat=dlmread(file_name)`, but I think that it only works with numbers.

I've also tried this:

```
mat=fileread(filename);
mat(mat==',') = ''
```

but the output is strange, `mat` is 1 By 72

====EDIT====

example of output (matrix 11By6):

```
RRSSTT
RRSTST
RRSTTS
RRTSST
RRTSTS
RRTTSS
RSRSTT
RSRTST
RSRTTS
RSSRTT
RSSTRT
```

Comment: What else have you tried? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html?

Comment: yes, I can read file with `text = fileread(filename)`, but after I need to delete commas

Comment: " I need to delete commas" - trivial in MATLAB. Please try it yourself and add some code to your question showing where you get stuck.

Comment: type into Google: Matlab read file with comma delimiter. You should see the Matlab function `textscan`, read the example that Mathwork gives and you should be able to do this yourself - after which you get to feel good about solving it on your own. Also, wild guessing here, but I think you can generate your data in Matlab using `perm` ? Anyone agrees?

Comment: yes, I generate the file with perms with: `alphabet='RRRSSSTTT';` `sequence = unique(perms(alphabet),'rows');`. But it's very useless generate it for long alphabet every times.

Comment: Actually, you sould use a cell-matrix, a "regular" matrix won't work or you just get a one column vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like a rep whore, but here is one of the many possible solutions.

Assuming your file is named test.csv -

```
fileID = fopen('test.csv');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %s %s %s %s %s' ,'Delimiter',',');
```

====EDIT====

if you don't want to write %s 6 times - do:

```
formatSpec = '%s';
N = 6;
C = textscan(fileID, repmat('%s', [1 N]),'Delimiter',',');
```

Again, this is just one of the many * many ways to do it.

This will generate a cell structure of 1 x 6, where each of the 6 cells represent a column of your String. You can now index it using curly brackets:

```
>> C{1}
>>ans = 

'R'
'R'
'R'
'R'
'R'
'R'
'R'
'R'
'R'
'R'
'R'
```

If you want a full cell structure where there is only 1 Char in each cell, you just have to do:

```
 V = horzcat(C{:}); %// size of V is 11x6

V = 

'R'    'R'    'S'    'S'    'T'    'T'
'R'    'R'    'S'    'T'    'S'    'T'
'R'    'R'    'S'    'T'    'T'    'S'
'R'    'R'    'T'    'S'    'S'    'T'
'R'    'R'    'T'    'S'    'T'    'S'
'R'    'R'    'T'    'T'    'S'    'S'
'R'    'S'    'R'    'S'    'T'    'T'
'R'    'S'    'R'    'T'    'S'    'T'
'R'    'S'    'R'    'T'    'T'    'S'
'R'    'S'    'S'    'R'    'T'    'T'
'R'    'S'    'S'    'T'    'R'    'T'
```

=====SECOND EDIT=====

To convert to Char Array:
Use Char

```
 T  = reshape(char(V(:)),size(V)) %// size of T is now 11*6 Char

>> T =
RRSSTT
RRSTST
RRSTTS
RRTSST
.
.
```

Comment: yes,  i did it, but if columns are more I have to change manually `'%s %s %s %s %s %s'`, I've edited with adding this detail, sorry.

Comment: I will save you the embarrassment of actually upvoting this in that case ;) Good explanation

Comment: @PietroZ. I have edited the solution to include the method where you do not have to write %s for multiple times.

Comment: thanks, I'm not able to generalize to generic N, but i've already obtained a cell array, but after I failed to convert it in a string array.

Comment: @Adriaan LOL, thanks, haven't been answering any questions recently, the apache-spark tag gets so little attention so it is better to be back here in Matlab for some reps :D

Comment: @PietroZ. I'm not sure what your question is, could you explain the structure of your desired result and how you want to index it?

Comment: I would to read it like `dlmread(file_name)` do with numbers. So referring to my example the output have to be a strings matrix 11By6.

Comment: @PietroZ. that **only** works if, and only if, all your columns have the same length. That is required since a matrix needs to have the same number of rows and columns all around

Comment: @PietroZ. Something like this?  `T  = reshape(char(V(:)),[11 6])` which generates a Char Array? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah! now it works!!! Only one last thing, have you tested this line `C = textscan(fileID,'%s',N,'Delimiter',',');`? For me doesn't work, it seems that it reads only first row.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have not used this for so long. It only reads the header (first line). The alternative is to use repmat which is horrible. `C = textscan(fileID, repmat('%s', [1 N]),'Delimiter',','); `I guess textscan is more used in structured CSV...http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html

Comment: thanks for your help, for now I use `if`. In the future I will improve this aspect.